# Java REST - Filter information to return

Tags: java, rest

Is there a design pattern or a well known solution to design a REST Service where the front-end of the app may call a same webservice for different information on an object.

Example:

```
WebServiceFull.class

@PATH('/car/')
public Response getCarInformation(@PathParam('id') long carId) {
   // Call Service/DAO
   // return the complete Car Object (may contain 50 properties for instance (color, size, age, factory, brand, ....)
}
```

What I'm wondering if possible/good:

```
WebServiceWanted.class
@PATH('/car/')
public Response getCarInformation(@PathParam('id') long carId, @QueryParam('info') List<String> infoWanted) {
   // Call Service/DAO with the List
   // Browse through the given list to only get from DataBase the needed info
   // return the partially complete Car Object
}
```

Comment: If you use Spring Data Rest, you can achieve such behavior by defining [projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#projections-excerpts).

Comment: Here's an example of how a Google API provides this capability.  https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details#fields

Comment: Jersey has [Entity Data Filtering](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html), which is pretty much what you are describing.

Comment: @NicholasSmith How is google parsing the fields when receiving the request? Reflection? Mapping? hand-made IF(...)s?